# JQGrid drag and drop issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, drag-and-drop

Hi I am using jqgrid  drag and drop between two different grids. I am able to drag the row to another grid only to the top of the other grid. Is there a way I can drag the row where ever I want??

Connecting two grids like shown below:

```
jQuery("#row1").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#row2'}); 
                jQuery("#row2").jqGrid('gridDnD',{connectWith:'#row1'});
```

**example:**

```
Grid1:       

row1<br>
row2<br>
row3<br>

Grid2:

row21<br>
row22
```

When I drag row1 from Grid1 I need that in between row21 and row22. But I am just able to drag it to top the list that is above row21.